# Android Storage Access Framework delete directory

Tags: android

When I need to open a file with SAF (from storage or from DocumentsProvider) I just call Intent :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType(TYPE_ALL);
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.excaption_not_found_open,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

When I need to delete a FILE I do just the same, except  OPEN_REQUEST_CODE - I change it with DELETE_REQUEST_CODE, get URI and call Delete() method.

The problem is I don't know how to delete DIRECTORY. I have a method that does it pragmatically, but I can't figure how to use it with standard file viewer - it only OPENS directory - there is no Intent to delete it... 
I guess I have to write my own File Manager to do that. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

Check this from the [Android Developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html):

[image]

Comment: I told you - I KNOW how to delete it in code. I cannot select directory to delete with system viewer. When I click on directory viewer OPENS it!