# How to delete a folder on Android 11?

Tags: java, android, delete-file

I have a doubt, how I can delete a folder on Android 11 (or 10)?

Have much answers here on Stack how to do it, but nothing of worked.

This code worked for me on Android 5:

```
 public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
      if (dir.isDirectory()) {
           String[] children = dir.list();
           for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                     return false;
                }
           }
      }

      // The directory is now empty so delete it
      return dir.delete();
 }
```

On newest versions of Android it not work. I noticed that there are applications that can to do this, so I imagine it is possible. Any answer about it?

Comment: And what is logcat saying ?

Comment: Look for scoped storage. You need to use content resolver

Comment: @PeterMmm Nothing more, but the deletion really returns false.

Comment: @cmak Ok, I'll read more about this. From what I've just seen, this is something from Android 11, correct?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5322390/9474700 check this

Comment: @behrad Not worked.

Comment: You should have started telling full path of folder. After that who created that folder and if it contains files. If it contains files then tell also who created them.

Comment: @Whats91356 Get the document folder https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#open-file
then delete it https://stackoverflow.com/a/31755101/11880323 There's no way to do it directly unless your app is granted the access all storage permission, which Play Store only allows to apps that really need it like file managers

Comment: @cmak Thanks cmak, it is a valious information, reading the articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android has done much to change its permission models around file access since Android 10 and 11. The preferred approach is to use [Scoped Storage APIs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage).

Many of the old file read/write permissions are on life support and will no longer work. If they do continue to work, then must justify to Google why you need them, and then go through a security approval by Google. You will only be granted approval if you app is classified as a file browser application, or the like.

Basically, the new model is to use Android's file browsers to gain access to read/write/update a particular file that the user selects, and defer the rest of the file management to Google's first-party applications. The access you get is based on what the user selected in the first-party file browser. You are then handed a URI back to your application with the proper permissions to perform the intended action, such as read/write/etc...

You may find this video useful:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjyYCUW-9tY

Comment: Interesting, it seems more secure. I'll check the content, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Context.deleteFile() ?

```
getApplicationContext().deleteFile(filename);
```

Comment: I tested that, not worked. The first answer has a good explanation the why it occurs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To delete all files inside the ExternalFilesDir

```
fun removeAllFilesInExternalFilesDir(context: Context, folder: String) {
    context.getExternalFilesDir(folder)?.listFiles()?.forEach {
        it.delete()
    }
}
```